# Using select all in drop down list and display in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have two controls a textbox and drop down list to search the database. I have added all to the drop down list that will allow the user to see all the data in the database; if the textbox is empty or not empty to show the employee and their positions (relating to what was entered in the textbox). What show be added to query?

```
  protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
        sqlConn.Open();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
        string sqlquery = "  SELECT CONCAT(c.FIRSTNAME, ' ', c.LASTNAME) AS 'EmployeeName' , Position FROM[TWCL_OPERATIONS].[dbo].[PP_Employee] c where CONCAT(c.FIRSTNAME, ' ', c.LASTNAME)  LIKE '%' + @EmployeeName + '%' and  position like '%' + @position + '%' ";

        com.CommandText = sqlquery;
        com.Connection = sqlConn;

        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeName", txtEmployeeName.Text.Trim());

        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@position", ddlPostion.SelectedItem.Text);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        sda.Fill(ds);

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
        {                 
            Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>window.alert('No Records Found!');window.location='AddEmployee.aspx';</script>");
        }
        else
        {
            grdEmployee.DataSource = ds;
            grdEmployee.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

[image: in grid]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the **All** text in to your query so in result its is looking for a position that is equal to **All**

```
position like '%All%'
```

You just need to add a condition in your btnSearch click event if the selected on ddlposition is equal to **All** then set the value on your parameter to a empty string.

```
 protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
            string positionvalue =string.Empty;
            string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
            sqlConn.Open();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
            string sqlquery = "  SELECT CONCAT(c.FIRSTNAME, ' ', c.LASTNAME) AS 'EmployeeName' , Position FROM[TWCL_OPERATIONS].[dbo].[PP_Employee] c where CONCAT(c.FIRSTNAME, ' ', c.LASTNAME)  LIKE '%' + @EmployeeName + '%' and  position like '%' + @position + '%' ";

            com.CommandText = sqlquery;
            com.Connection = sqlConn;

            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeName", txtEmployeeName.Text.Trim());

            if(ddlPostion.SelectedItem.Text == "All"){
                 positionvalue  ="";
             }
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@position", positionvalue  );
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            sda.Fill(ds);

            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
            {                 
                Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>window.alert('No Records Found!');window.location='AddEmployee.aspx';</script>");
            }
            else
            {
                grdEmployee.DataSource = ds;
                grdEmployee.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help